# How to create undo checkout recursively in clearcase in context menu

Tags: clearcase

I'm trying to create undo checkout recursively...,   context menu with arguments (I'm using `clearmenuadmin.exe`)

```
/c cleartool lsco -r -cvi -fmt "unco -rm %n\n"$dir|cleartool
```

but its not working.. any idea on how to do this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: do put a space between the `%n\n"` and `$dir`.

In this case, the `-fmt` part will not ensure the execution, even piped to cleartool

Perhaps

```
/c cleartool lsco -r -cvi -fmt "cleartool unco -rm %n\n"$dir|cmd
```

would work, but I doubt it: the problem is visible when considering *all* the command launched when configure with the `clearmenuadmin.exe`:

```
cmd /c cleartool lsco -r -cvi -fmt "cleartool unco -rm %n\n"$dir|cmd
```

The `|cmd` or `|ct` would apply to the first cmd, not to the cleartool command.

I would rather use and external script (to wrap the `unco` command)

```
/c myUnco.cmd $dir
```

with myUnco.cmd stored in a directory referenced by your %PATH% environment variable, with;

```
cleartool lsco -r -cvi -fmt "cleartool unco -rm %n\n" %1|cleartool
```

Here (in the `.cmd` script) `%1` represents the `$dir` passed through the clearcase contextual menu.