# Convert checked out file to hijacked file in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

I have a number of files that were automatically checked out (due to how I'd set Eclipse's ClearCase plugin up) when I edited them.  I now realize that those should have been Hijacked instead.

Is their a direct method for converting from checked out to hijacked?

I realize I could undo the checkout and have it generate the .keep file, then hijack the file, and paste the .keep file's contents into the hijacked file, but I have several dozen files to fix and would prefer not to have to do the workaround if possible.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a file is checked out, it will be remember by ClearCase (server) as checked out.
So `unco` (undo checkout) remains the safest route, with a command similar to "[How to create undo checkout recursively in clearcase in context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012572/how-to-create-undo-checkout-recursively-in-clearcase-in-context-menu)".
(on Unix, it is [easier to script](http://anthony-yio.blogspot.fr/2007/05/clearcase-check-inuncheck-out-all.html))

You only need to use `unco -keep`, instead of `unco -rm`, in order to generate the .keep files.

Finally, a simple script can:

- find all the .keep file
- copy them over the (not checked out) respective file: that is enough to hijack them.